# Wasserstein distance to the set of Gaussians, relation to Boltzman dissipation rate

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$
I am interested in the 2-Wasserstein distance for probabilities over $\RR^n$,
$W_2(μ,ν)=\left(\inf\int_{\RR^n×\RR^n}|w−v|^2dπ(v,w)\right)^1/2$
where the infimum is taken over the probabilities $π$ having marginals $μ$ and $ν$.

Let GP denote the subset of probabilities that have a Gaussian density. Is there any close formula, or approximate formula, for the distance (in terms of $W_2$) from a given $μ$ to GP ? How can it be related to the entropy dissipation rate encountered in the Boltzman equation, where one integrate the non-negative quantity
$$(f(v^∗)f(v′∗)−f(v)f(v′))(\log(f(v^∗)f(v′^∗))−\log(f(v)f(v′)))$$
where $f$ is the density of the velocity distribution and the arguments are constrained by (conservation of momentum and energy)
$v+v′=v^∗+v′^∗$,$\|v\|^2+\|v\|^2=\|v^∗\|^2+\|v′^∗\|^2$.

Notice that, for consistency, the Wasserstein distance should be applied to measures with a density, i.e. of the form
$%1ρf(v)dv,$
$ρ:=∫f(v)dv$.

Comment: I tried to convert everything into tex (people here do not appreciate posts they can barely decipher…) - please edit if I made some mistakes.